# Cannot map an object ? Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, point-of-sale, receipt

So i'm currently making a receipt for my POS app.

I currently have stored an array in my database as:
[mongodb collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29crF.png)

And I want to map them to a receipt page

```
function renderTable(orderlist) {
    return (
      <tr className='service'>
        <td className='tableitem'>
          <p className='itemtext'>{orderlist.name}</p>
        </td>
        <td className='tableitem'>
          <p className='itemtext'>{orderlist.qty}</p>
        </td>
        <td className='tableitem'>
          <p className='itemtext'>{orderlist.subtotal}</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }



const showReceipt = ({
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    isSubmitting,
  }) => {
    return (
      <div id='bot'>
        <div id='table'>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr className='tabletitle'>
                <td className='item'>
                  <h2>Item</h2>
                </td>
                <td className='Hours'>
                  <h2>Qty</h2>
                </td>
              </tr>
              {values.order_list.map((orders) => {
                renderTable(orders.order_list);
              })}
              <tr className='tabletitle'>
                <td />
                <td className='Rate'>
                  <h2>tax</h2>
                </td>
                <td className='payment'>
                  <h2>$419.25</h2>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr className='tabletitle'>
                <td />
                <td className='Rate'>
                  <h2>Total</h2>
                </td>
                <td className='payment'>
                  <h2>{values.total}</h2>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div id='legalcopy'>
          {/* <p className='legal'>
            <strong>Thank you for your business!</strong>&nbsp; Payment is
            expected within 31 days; please process this invoice within that
            time. There will be a 5% interest charge per month on late invoices.
          </p> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

And it is currently showing me this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I can't for some reason map this one particular object.

I can, however, Return them as string with :
[JSON.Stringify(orderlist)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq0SC.png)

I can also log the object in [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuBq6.png)

For whatever reason I just can't map them. I want the function to return a row for each Order_list content

Comment: Please show console.log of `values`?

Comment: @Viet [Here you go](https://i.imgur.com/7lTJI2O.png)

Comment: Can you show how the `values` defined?

Comment: It's defined from a redux reducer result which is dispatched by a getSingleOrder(id) redux action which got its data from get API

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time with these problems, your `values` are available at some point, but since you are getting them from an api and that takes time, not during your first render.
Before mapping over it, check if `values` is alreaady set and otherwise show a loading indicator.

Comment: You might be right, I tried to map just the `values`, and it also returns `undefined` although I wonder why returning the `values.total` works just fine, whereas mapping `values.order_list` returns `undefined`. Is it because mapping takes more time? if so,  what can I do to map `values.order_list`?  edit: mapping just the `values` actually returns `map is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

When you call api. The `values.order_list` is a initial value you defined on the reducer. So if you don't defined the initial of `order_list`, `values.order_list` is undefined. You can use optional chaining to check before call map like this.

```
values.order_list?.map
```

Comment: Thanks! checking before the mapping with `values.order_list?.map` doesn't return anything with no errors. How do I tell it to wait until `values.order_list` have value in it, then execute the mapping?